# Query related to rails Cron Job

Tags: cron

```
2**** cd $PROD_RAILS_ROOT && ./rake --silent users:update RAILS_ENV=production
```

What does 2 mean here? Is it every 2 min.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

each hour to the second minute your job is executed.

- 00:02
- 01:02
- 02:02
- 03:02
- 04:02
  etc...

If you want each 2 minutes it's :

```
*/2 * * * *
```